# Gravar rota de acordo com o avanço

Tags: ios, gps, mapkit

Como gravar rota utilizando `CLLocation` e `Mapkit`, e marcar vários pontos no mapa atualizando conforme se movimenta?

Comment: Você precisa especificamente somente com o CLLocation e MapKit? Ou poderia ser com o Google Maps?